# How do I fill only the next value in an array? - C#

Tags: arrays, input, user-input

I just want to take an input from the user, increase the length of the array by one when I do, and fill that new space in the array with the input the user put in. I do not want to fill the entire array with a singular value.

The only thing I could think to try was this:

```
char[] array = new char[10];

char input = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = input;
    Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
    break;
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Why doesn't this obviously not work?

Answer (score 0):

Use a list, not an array, then you can add as you go.

```
List<char> list = new();
while (true)
{
    list.Add(Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine()));
}
```

You can still access the elements of a list like an array.

```
Console.WriteList(list[4]);
```